# Account Page Jumping down to Visualforce Page Embedded in Layout

Tags: visualforce

I have a Visualforce page that is embedded into my Account Page Layout and whenever I click on an Account it loads down to the Visualforce page and not at the top of the page. Does anyone know why this is happening?

*EDIT*

Here is what I have right now.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" tabStyle="Account">
<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:iframe src="{!Account.Extracted_RRID_URL__c}" scrolling="true" id="theFrame"/>
</apex:pageBlock>
<script>
    setFocus = function() { return; }
</script>
```

Thanks,
Chad

Comment: Can you include some code from the VF?  Is there any Javascript that causes the page to focus on a form element?

Comment: Edited original post

Comment: Here is the really weird thing. If I load an Account (Sys Admin) it does not jump down to the VF. It is only the other Standard Users that are getting this problem.

Comment: was this ever resolved?  I have a client who is saying their Account pages are jumping down to the canvas app (iframe)...  I don't have access to their salesforce instance... but our other clients have not reported this issue with our canvas app.